# Varios errores en practica de POO para hacer una petición a la BBDD

Tags: php, mysql

Hola y muy buenos dias a todos, estoy dando una clase en la que me explican a cerca de POO para hacer una conexión a una tabla de mysql

(Utilizando XAMPP y reciclando un excel para crear una tabla con supuestos articulos varios a los que poder consultar. De ahi que existan acentos en los campos.)

en la que siguiendo paso a paso lo que hace el profesor, me da los siguientes errores:

Notice: Undefined variable: conexion_db in C:\xampp\htdocs\cursoPHPPildoras\POO\conexion.php on line 12

Notice: Trying to get property 'connect_errno' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\cursoPHPPildoras\POO\conexion.php on line 14

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function set_charset() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\cursoPHPPildoras\POO\conexion.php:22 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\cursoPHPPildoras\POO\devuelve_productos.php(8): Conexion->Conexion() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\cursoPHPPildoras\POO\index.php(5): DevuelveProductos->DevuelveProductos() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\cursoPHPPildoras\POO\conexion.php on line 22

Concluyo la explicación añadiendo que soy un iniciado y que no vengo buscado las soluciones de mis deberes o quehaceres, busco aprender del error y de las opiniones de expertos como vosotros para poder seguir nutriendome de información de una gran comunidad como la de los desarrolladores para en un futuro poder dedicarme a esto y poder así yo tambien poder también ayudar correctamente a la gente. Aún me queda un largo camino.

El curso del profesor que ando siguiendo es este. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tA40GGmzrKY&list=PLU8oAlHdN5BkinrODGXToK9oPAlnJxmW_&index=57

Aqui va mi código:

````
//1.   config.php

 <?php

define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

define('DB_USUARIO', 'root');

define('DB_CONTRA', '');

define('DB_NOMBRE', 'pruebas');

define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

?>   


//2.    conexion.php

 <?php

require ("config.php");

class Conexion {


    protected $conexion_db;

    public function Conexion(){

      $this->$conexion_db=new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USUARIO, DB_CONTRA, DB_NOMBRE);

        if($this->conexion_db->connect_errno) {


            echo "Fallo al conectar con MYSQL: " . $this->conexion_db->connect_error;

            return;
        }

        $this->conexion_db->set_charset(DB_CHARSET);
    }
}


?> 


//3.    devuelve_productos.php

<?php
require "conexion.php";

class DevuelveProductos extends Conexion{

    public function DevuelveProductos(){

        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function get_productos(){

        $resultado=$this->conexion_db->query('SELECT * FROM PRODUCTOS');

        $productos=$resultado->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        return $productos;
    }
}


?> 


//4.        index.php

 <?php

    require "devuelve_productos.php";

    $productos=new DevuelveProductos();

    $array_productos=$productos->get_productos();


?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="widht=device-width, user-
    scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximun-scale=1, minimun-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

   <?php

    foreach ($array_productos as $elemento){

        echo "<table><tr><td>";
        echo $elemento['CÓDIGOARTÍCULO'] . "</td><td>";
        echo $elemento['NOMBREARTÍCULO'] . "</td><td>";
        echo $elemento['SECCIÓN'] . "</td><td>";
        echo $elemento['PRECIO'] . "</td><td>";
        echo $elemento['FECHA'] . "</td><td>";
        echo $elemento['IMPORTADO'] . "</td><td>";
        echo $elemento['PAÍSDEORIGEN'] . "</td><td></tr></table>";

        echo "<br>";
        echo "<br>";



    }

   ?>

</body>

</html> ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.- El primer error que veo:

```
$this->$conexion_db
```

deberia ser sin el $:

```
$this->conexion_db
```

.- el segundo viene derivado del primero, ya que inicialmente el valor de `$this->conexion_db` es nulo (la anterior linea no lo ha definido correctamente) y por eso la llamada a un metodo desde un objeto null te da error.

.- en el de `setcharset` ocurre lo mismo, es debido al primero que no define la variable

Comment: De acuerdo, lo acabo de rervisar y efectivamente!! ese era el error que me daba el pantallazo, una vez mas, craso error mio el de novato, sobre sintaxis. Muchisimas gracias por tu aporte!!!